# How to fix this fibonacci batch lister?

Tags: batch-file, variables, fibonacci

I've researched about *operand and operators*, *set /a* , and *setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion* from this website but still somehow my code ends up telling
me that my operand is missing.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color 0a
title Fibonacci Lister
:Fibonacci
cls
set /a n1=1
echo %n1%
set /a n2=1
echo %n2%
set /a j=3
:loopfunction
set /a n%j%=!n%j-1%!+!n%j-2%!
echo !n%j%!
set /a j=%j%+1
goto :loopfunction
```

So I wanted to know what is the problem here. It is probably in line 14 where
the code is complex and hard to understand easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line `#14`, you were using a variables named `%j-1%` and `%j-2%` which weren't declared.

**Updated Script:**

```
@echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    color 0a
    title Fibonacci Lister
:Fibonacci
    set /a n1=1
    echo %n1%
    set /a n2=1
    echo %n2%
    set /a j=3
:loopfunction
    set /a j1=j-1&set /a j2=j-2
    set /a n%j%=!n%j1%!+!n%j2%!
    if "!n%j%!"=="1836311903" goto :EOF
    echo !n%j%!
    set /a j=j+1
goto :loopfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually works! I've added ping localhost>nul between line 18 and line 19 to delay the generation process down to a viewable time frame.

Comment: Oh so that fixes the negative value appearing when reaching higher values. Great!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set n1=0
    set n2=1
:loop
    echo %n2%
    set /a "n2=n1+n2" & set "n1=%n2%"
    if %n2% gtr 0 goto loop
```

Comment: I appreciated your answer which may lead to newer ideas to simplify my code down to a more reasonable way possible but it didn't fix the original code I've posted so I can only give you an up-vote but it didn't solve my entitled problem. Sorry.

Comment: @kornkaobat, I saw the Sam Denty answer solves your problem, so, there is not any reason for an answer solving the problem in the same way. My only intention was to include an alternative way of solving the task just in case someone finding this question could find it useful.

Comment: Oh okay then. So there's less replicated question and further readers can find more varieties of answers to solve the question. Thanks for clarifying!